# Is it possible to connect an OutputStream to the download window of a browser fron a java applet?

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet

see, i am developing a web application that downloads files from a server via http requests, but in a case the file isn't in the server but in the applet itself, i mean, some binary content is dynamically generated inside the applet and it must be downloaded. Of course i can use the java libraries to save the file in the client file system (if the applet is a signed one), but i was wondering if it can be done connecting the java OutputStream to the browser's download window, in other words, start a download from an applet.
Am i a crazy person ?

by the way, is it possible to do something similar from javascript ?

Comment: Just a note: proper way to thank the answering person is to up-vote his answer and if the answer is acceptable, well, accept it by clicking a tick mark left to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to get around security by attaching the output of an applet to the standard file download mechanisms of a browser.

OTOH, since the Next Generation Java Plug-In, it is no longer necessary to have a signed and trusted applet in order to save files(/bytes) to the local file-system.  Chase the links in the [Applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) for more details.  For a demo. of using the JNLP API services (that the plug-in2 hooks into for this functionality) see the [File service demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Answer (score 1):

You can if e.g. you upload the file to the server and then force browser (via [LiveConnect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html) or otherwise) to open that file from the server.

As far as I'm aware, there's no cross-browser way to emulate downloading from within an applet. So you should create that download yourself, and let browser do what it does best.

Obviously, it might well make sense to move the actual creation of the stream to your server side.